# MySQL Query to retrieve all values of a grouped column that's been filtered

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, group-concat

Say I have the following defined tables:

```
Table `content`:
===============
id unsigned int(11)
title varchar(500)

Table `satellite`:
===============
id unsigned int(11)
label varchar(250)

Table `content_satellite`:
===============
content_id unsigned int(11)
satellite_id unsigned int(11)
```

If I wanted to get a list of content rows that contain a GROUP_CONCAT()'ted list of associated satellites, FILTERED on a particular satellite type, what would the query be?

Using the following query:

```
SELECT 
c.title,
GROUP_CONCAT(s.id) as satellite_ids
FROM content c
LEFT JOIN content_satellite cs ON cs.content_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN satellite s ON cs.satellite_id = s.id
WHERE satellite = 2
GROUP BY c.id;
```

The resulting rows would have satellite_ids containing ONLY a single value "2" whether or not a particular content row is associated to multiple satellite types...

How can I query these tables to retrieve a column that contains ALL satellite ids associated with each content rows that come back while filtering on a particular satellite type?

EDIT - MySQL 5.5 is the Database type (didn't realize that mattered for a common basic SQL query such as this)

EDIT2 - Left the GROUP by off my sql query

Comment: what RDMS and version are you running?

Comment: MySQL 5.5, sorry. didn't realize that mattered in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query concatenates all IDs and gives you a random title. And of course when you only select satellite ID #2 then you only see #2.

First of all, you don't want to aggregate *all* records. You want groups. You want one record per content, so group by content. As there may be duplicate titles, better group by content id.

```
SELECT 
  c.id,
  c.title,
  GROUP_CONCAT(distinct cs.satellite_id order by cs.satellite_id) as satellite_ids
FROM content c
LEFT JOIN content_satellite cs ON cs.content_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.id;
```

EDIT: To get those contents that have satellite #2 in their list use HAVING with an appropriate case expression:

```
SELECT 
  c.id,
  c.title,
  GROUP_CONCAT(distinct cs.satellite_id order by cs.satellite_id) as satellite_ids
FROM content c
LEFT JOIN content_satellite cs ON cs.content_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.id
HAVING MAX( CASE WHEN cs.satellite_id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) = 1;
```

Comment: Hey, sorry, I left the group by line off my sql query. I put it in there... you left out the WHERE clause in your query, which results in the intended result of having the entirety of the satellite ids included in the content rows, but what happens when you need to select all those rows that have a specific satellite ID? You get ONLY ONE satellite ID in the group concat result?

Comment: Ah, I see, you want the same result, but only those records having satallite ID #2 in their list. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: almost there... What I need to do is DISPLAY ALL SATELLITES for each content row in the result list, yet only show the content rows that are linked at LEAST to satellite_id = 2... In other words, I want to display a list of content, and every satellite row linked to each content in that list, but I only want to show rows of content that happen to be linked to a particular satellite row. I still want to display EVERY satellite that content is linked to, but I ONLY want to display the content rows that are linked to satellite reow ID 2...  ACTUALLY I think what you have there does it... i'll try